# How to call attribute values to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<apex:form >
<c:AutoCompleteV2 allowClear="true" importJquery="true" labelField="name" SObject="Quote_Line_Item__c" valuefield="name" targetField="6" style="width:175px"  inputFieldId="Name" />
<input type="button" value="GET" id="0"  onclick="myfunction($('input[id$=inputFieldId]').val());"/>     
<c:AutoCompleteV2 allowClear="true" importJquery="true" labelField="name" SObject="Quote_Line_Item__c" valuefield="name" targetField="5" style="width:175px" id="Name1"/>  
 <input type="button" value="GET" id="0"  onclick="myfunction($('input[id$=targetField]').val());"/>     
<c:AutoCompleteV2 allowClear="true" importJquery="true" labelField="name" SObject="Quote_Line_Item__c" valuefield="name" targetField="4" style="width:175px" inputFieldId="Name2"/>
 <input type="button" value="GET1" id="1"  onclick="myfunction($('input[id$=valuefield]').val());"/>       
<c:AutoCompleteV2 allowClear="true" importJquery="true" labelField="name" SObject="Quote_Line_Item__c" valuefield="name" targetField="3" style="width:175px" inputFieldId="Name3"/>   
 <input type="button" value="GET2" id="2"  onclick="myfunction($('input[id$=valuefield]').val());"/>    
<c:AutoCompleteV2 allowClear="true" importJquery="true" labelField="name" SObject="Quote_Line_Item__c" valuefield="name" targetField="2" style="width:175px" inputFieldId="Name4"/>  
 <input type="button" value="GET3" id="3"  onclick="myfunction($('input[id$=SObject]').val());"/> 
</apex:form> 
<script>
function myfunction(value){
alert(value);
}
</script>
```

How can i call attribute values in javascript ?

i am getting error as undefined in alert box .

I want to know call attribute to get that value ?

Comment: myfunction($('c:AutoCompleteV2').attr(targetField)) tried but not working

Comment: then provide full details in your question..., you did not mention anywhere `need values of c:AutoCompleteV2`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, i believe that you don't really need that evaluating of code, that is written in ur onclick attribute. Better write a selector in a custom attribute and then do with it whatever you want in your function.
But if you really want to do what you have asked: (try Get3)

```js
for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName("input").length; i++) {   

 document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].onclick = function(){
       alert(this.getAttribute("attribute"));               eval(  this.getAttribute("attribute"));     
                                                           };

                                                                       }
```

```html
<apex:form >
<c:AutoCompleteV2 allowClear="true" importJquery="true" labelField="name" SObject="Quote_Line_Item__c" valuefield="name" targetField="6" style="width:175px"  inputFieldId="Name" />
<input type="button" value="GET" id="0"  attribute="$('input[id$=inputFieldId]').val()"/>     
<c:AutoCompleteV2 allowClear="true" importJquery="true" labelField="name" SObject="Quote_Line_Item__c" valuefield="name" targetField="5" style="width:175px" id="Name1"/>  
 <input type="button" value="GET" id="0"  attribute="$('input[id$=targetField]').val()"/>     
<c:AutoCompleteV2 allowClear="true" importJquery="true" labelField="name" SObject="Quote_Line_Item__c" valuefield="name" targetField="4" style="width:175px" inputFieldId="Name2"/>
 <input type="button" value="GET1" id="1"  attribute="$('input[id$=valuefield]').val()"/>       
<c:AutoCompleteV2 allowClear="true" importJquery="true" labelField="name" SObject="Quote_Line_Item__c" valuefield="name" targetField="3" style="width:175px" inputFieldId="Name3"/>   
 <input type="button" value="GET2" id="2"  attribute="$('input[id$=valuefield]').val()"/>    
<c:AutoCompleteV2 allowClear="true" importJquery="true" labelField="name" SObject="Quote_Line_Item__c" valuefield="name" targetField="2" style="width:175px" inputFieldId="Name4"/>  
 <input type="button" value="GET3" id="3"  attribute="console.log(1)"/> 
</apex:form>
```

or jquery version

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "input" ).click(function() {
  alert($(this).attr('attribute'));
  $.globalEval($(this).attr('attribute') );
});
});
```

But i'd recommend you to review your task and use a structure like this: input gets the value of the attribute of the element with id=Name+input.id

```js
for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName("input").length; i++) {   

 document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].onclick = function(){
                   alert(document.getElementById("Name"+this.getAttribute("id")).getAttribute(this.getAttribute("attribute")));
                                                               };

                                                                           }
```

```html
<apex:form >
<c:AutoCompleteV2 allowClear="true" importJquery="true" labelField="name" SObject="Quote_Line_Item__c" valuefield="name" targetField="6" style="width:175px"  inputFieldId="Name" id="Name0"/>
<input type="button" value="GET" id="0"  attribute="inputFieldId"/>     
<c:AutoCompleteV2 allowClear="true" importJquery="true" labelField="name" SObject="Quote_Line_Item__c" valuefield="name" targetField="5" style="width:175px" id="Name1"/>  
 <input type="button" value="GET" id="0"  attribute="targetField"/>     
<c:AutoCompleteV2 allowClear="true" importJquery="true" labelField="name" SObject="Quote_Line_Item__c" valuefield="name" targetField="4" style="width:175px" inputFieldId="Name2" id="Name2"/>
 <input type="button" value="GET1" id="1"  attribute="allowclear"/>       
<c:AutoCompleteV2 allowClear="true" importJquery="true" labelField="name" SObject="Quote_Line_Item__c" valuefield="name" targetField="3" style="width:175px" inputFieldId="Name3" id="Name3"/>   
 <input type="button" value="GET2" id="2"  attribute="SObject"/>    
<c:AutoCompleteV2 allowClear="true" importJquery="true" labelField="name" SObject="Quote_Line_Item__c" valuefield="name" targetField="2" style="width:175px" inputFieldId="Name4" id="Name4"/>  
 <input type="button" value="GET3" id="3"  attribute="importJquery"/> 
</apex:form>
```

jquery

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "input" ).click(function() {

      alert($("#Name"+$(this).attr('id')).attr($(this).attr('attribute')));

});
});
```